# racket/draw: get list of font face names?

Tags: fonts, racket, pict

Is it possible to get a list of available font face names in Racket?

I want all values of `x` such that `(text "Kimkoh" x)` returns a pict with a unique font face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`(get-face-list)`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/Drawing_Functions.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fdraw..rkt%29._get-face-list%29%29) returns the list you want.

Try this in DrRacket 6.12 (or newer):

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/draw pict)

(table 2
       (for/fold ([acc '()]
                  #:result (reverse acc))
                 ([face (in-list (get-face-list))]
                  [i (in-range 10)])
         (list* (text "Kimkoh" face) (text face) acc))
       lb-superimpose lb-superimpose 20 5)
```